# Custom attribute dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, magento-1, html, attribute-set

I am overriding the `catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` file, but I notice how frustrating it is to change the style of the `<select>` and `<option>` elements.

Is there a way to change this `<select>` and `<option>` combination to, for example, an `<ul>` and `<li>` combination?

Comment: If my answer help you then mark as accepted so other can take benefit from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that file there is a variable `echo $_jsonConfig` if you print this then it will give you json data for that, just iterate that json and create the structure that you want.

> Note : please take backup of that file

Hope this will help you

Comment: Ah, that should fix the problem. Thanks alot!

Comment: you are always welcome :)

Comment: If my answer help you then mark as accepted so other can take benefit from that

Comment: Yes ofcourse, sorry, almost forgot about it :p

Comment: Its Okay.  it will help others too   :)